# Openpyxl giving error "Process finished with exit code 0", objects not callable

Tags: pycharm, openpyxl

I am new to Python, I am using `PyCharm` and intalled `openpyxl` from `file>settings>project interpreter`.

When I am running a code it is giving error like:

```
     object is not callable 

     Process finished with exit code 0

     TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

When I am running code

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
wb.sheetnames`
```

it gives me error saying

```
    `Process finished with exit code 0`
```

When I am using

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
wb.active()`
```

It is giving

```
     ` Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Shankar/.PyCharmEdu2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", 
    line 3, in <module>
        wb.active()
     TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable
```

Thanks

PS - i am new to python, using pycharm, and book called "Automate the 
boring stuff", i am facing errors after installing openpyxl module.

Answer (score 0):

When pycharm shows `Process finished with exit code 0` This normally means that the program is done and did not throw any errors. So a good thing :)

`wb.active()` is not a method but a WorkSheet object. Access it like this: `my_worksheet = wb.active` Without the parentheses `()`

Read more on the difference between method objects and other types of objects here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes